# C#. How can I pass my json deserializing method as Async?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

So here's what I am trying to do and what I have accomplished.

```
private static T _getjson<T>(string url) where T : new()
        {
            using (var w = new WebClient())
            {
                var json_data = string.Empty;
                // attempt to download JSON data as a string
                try
                {
                    json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
                // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data) : new T();
            }
        }
```

This method (when called) is used like so:

```
var onlineornot = ("http://blah.com");
var chatters = _getjson<Rootobject>(onlineornot);
```

`<Rootobject>` being a class set up like this:

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public _Links _links { get; set; }
        public int chatter_count { get; set; }
        public Chatters chatters { get; set; }
        public Stream stream { get; set; }
        public Stream game { get; set; }
        public _Links2 _links2 { get; set; }
    }
```

For the most part, it works but it causes my app to hang every time I call `_getJson`. I was wondering how I could use Async in this case, while maintaining the ability to get the properties from `<Rootobject>`.

Comment: `_getjson` The framework design guidelines are coming to get you, Pat.  And WebClient offers async methods.  What's the problem with using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebClient` class has a `DownloadStringAsync()` method ([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202(v=vs.110).aspx)) you can use.

[Here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) is a brief blog post that shows how you can use `async`/`await` to prevent your UI from blocking.

ex:

```
private static async Task<T> _getjson<T>(string url) where T : new()
{
    using (var w = new WebClient())
    {
        var json_data = string.Empty;
        // attempt to download JSON data as a string
        try
        {
            json_data = await w.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data) : new T();
    }
}

public async void Button1_Click(...)
{
    ...
    var onlineornot = ("http://example.com");
    var chatters = await _getjson<Rootobject>(onlineornot);
    ...
}
```

Comment: as much as i appreciate that response. I have already tried this. This indeed DOES work but does not allow you to call RootObject properties. instead of being able to get public `Chatters chatters { get; set; I get Async properties. Test this code if you dont understand what I mean. when you use chatters.property, it wont be the same as if you used plain DownloadString. It shows me different properties when I use async for deserializing for some reason.

Comment: @Pat Miller Are you using the `await` keyword when calling `_getjson()`? IE: `await _getjson<Rootobject>(onlineornot);` instead of `_getjson<Rootobject>(onlineornot);` If you don't, the call to `_getjson` will give you a reference to the `Task<>` object created rather than waiting and giving you a reference to the `Rootobject` object.

Comment: I think you might have solved it you genius <3 :P, let me test lol.

Comment: Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Uri' and its at this code. json_data = await w.DownloadStringAsync(url);

Comment: Ah, yes, `DownloadStringTaskAsync()` should work, or you can create a `Uri` object from your string (as I did in the my edit just now): `w.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url))`.

Comment: I just tried and got the error. Cannot await void. assuming it has to do with the new url youre making?

Comment: No, I didn't read the docs closely enough. You want to use `DownloadStringTaskAsync()`. `DownloadStringAsync` doesn't provide a return value (ie. `void`). Updating my answer.

Comment: :) Yea I use task but I wasn't aware that you HAD to use Task to get a return value, this does indeed work though.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer, use `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202(v=vs.110).aspx

Modify your code like this:

```
private static async Task<T> _getjson<T>(string url) where T : new()
{
    using (var w = new WebClient())
    {
        var json_data = string.Empty;
        // attempt to download JSON data as a string
        try
        {
           json_data = await w.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data) : new T();
    }
}
```

Also, the key thing here is to make sure this is not executed on the main UI thread.

Comment: how would i put this method in another thread with a string arg? Also this doesnt allow me to get properties of the RootObject class. When i set a var to _getjson<RootObject>(url) I cant call properties from that var. like i cant get "game" from the class when using chatters.game if I made chatters = _getjson<RootObject>(url). you know what i mean?

Comment: Is the RootObject an abstract root class?  If so, change the where T : new() to where T : RootObject.  Then you have access to the properties.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: youre answer was correct as well <3. I thank you a lot.

Comment: DownloadStringAsync returns void. Do you mean DownloadStringTaskAsync?